# JavaScript close button works on one page, but not on another page

Tags: javascript, magento

Does anyone know why a JavaScript button would work on one page but not on another page?

Within Magento I turned error messages to display as pop-ups, and used Java for the close button. It works on one page, but on another it doesn't. In Safari the Errormessage that won't close displays repeatedly, twice and one of them will close.

Code I'm using within Messages.php:

```
$html .= '<a class="msgclose" href="#" onclick="document.getElementById(\'messages\').style.visibility=\'hidden\'">x</a>';
```

It works on an individual product page (when adding a product to the bag) but won't work on the sign in page when entering an incorrect password.

Working close button: http://www.moramoraswimwear.com/magento/index.php/test-5
Failing Button: https://web72.secure-secure.co.uk/moramoraswimwear.com/magento/index.php/customer/account/login/

Any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not working because you have two elements with the ID `#messages` on the same page, most likely due to the account create and account login blocks containing the error messages HTML.  You cannot have two elements with the same ID on the same page.

You need to remove the error messages block from the account create/login blocks, and move it into their parent block so it only appears once on the page.

[image: Messages Duplicated IDs]

What's happened when you click the close button is that it's selecting the first `#messages` it finds and setting the visibility on it.  The second one is completely ignored (because again, it assumes there is only ever one on the page).

Comment: If my solution worked for you, please be sure to accept my answer so others with the same issue are able to find it easier.